# Getting the specific blog post from the user that is logged in - with flask and sqlalchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

In the def user(): function i need to get the blog post for the user that is currently logged in into a variable so i can pass it to my html file through the render_template() command. It is honestly probably something super simple but i just didn't know how to word it very well when i was doing google searches. Thank You!

```
class users(db.Model):
    _id = db.Column("id", db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20))
    password = db.Column(db.String(30))
    blog = db.Column(db.String(500))
    admin = db.Column(db.String(5))

    def __init__(self, username, password, blog, admin):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.blog = blog
        self.admin = admin
        db.create_all()

values = users.query.all()

@app.route("/create_account", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def create_account():
    if request.method == "POST":
        create_user = request.form["create_username"]
        create_pass = request.form["create_password"]
        create_admin = request.form["create_adminer"]
        found_user = users.query.filter_by(username=create_user).first()
        found_pass = users.query.filter_by(password=create_pass).first()
        found_adminer = users.query.filter_by(admin=create_admin).first()
        try:
            if found_user.username and found_pass.password:
                flash("Account already exists")
                return render_template("login.html")
        except:
            if create_admin == "True":
                usr = users(create_user, create_pass, 'Your Blog Will Go Here', create_admin)
                db.session.add(usr)
                db.session.commit()
                flash('Account Created')
                return redirect(url_for("login"))
            else:
                usr = users(create_user, create_pass, 'Your Blog Will Go Here', "")
                db.session.add(usr)
                db.session.commit()
                flash('Account Created')
                return redirect(url_for("login"))
    else:
        return render_template('create_account.html')

@app.route("/login", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def login():
    if request.method == "POST":
        use = request.form["usern"]
        pas = request.form["passw"]
        found_username = users.query.filter_by(username=use, password=pas).first()
        print(found_username.username)
        try:
            adm = request.form['adminer']
            found_admin = users.query.filter_by(admin=adm).first()
            if found_username.username == use and found_username.password == pas and adm == 'True':
                session['username'] = use
                session['password'] = pas
                session['admin'] = adm
                return redirect(url_for("user"))
            else:
                if found_username.username == use and found_username.password == pas:
                    session['username'] = use
                    session['password'] = pas
                    return redirect(url_for("user"))
        except:
            flash('Incorrect Login Information')
            return render_template('login.html')        
    else:
        return render_template('login.html')

@app.route("/user")
def user():
    use = session['username']
    pas = session['password']
    values = users.query.all()
    try:


    while True:
         for item in values:
             print(item.blog)
             found_user = users.query.filter_by(username=use, password=pas, blog=item.blog).first()
             if found_user.username == use and found_user.password == pas and found_user.blog == item.blog:
             return render_template("user.html", username=use, blogs=item.blog)
             break
             #I know there isn't and except statement, will add it once i get the basic code structure i need. Thank You!

@app.route("/logout")
def logout():
    session.pop("username", None)
    session.pop("password", None)
    session.pop("admin", None)
    flash("You have been logged out", 'warning')
    return redirect(url_for('login'))
    #return render_template('login.html')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    db.create_all()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the solution:

```
@app.route("/user")
def user():
    #global values
    try:
        use = session['username']
        pas = session['password']
        values = users.query.all()
        while True:
            for item in values:
                print(item.blog)
                found_user = users.query.filter_by(username=use, password=pas, blog=item.blog).first()
                try:
                    if found_user.username == use and found_user.password == pas and found_user.blog == item.blog:
                        return render_template("user.html", username=use, blogs=item.blog)
                        break
                except:
                    pass
    except:
        flash("Need to Login First")
        return redirect(url_for("login"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick disclaimer I am using peewee not SQLalchemy so I cannot just write you the code you need.
If you simply want the value of the "blog" column from your database based on the current user you could try to make a query that goes along the lines of this:

```py
blog        = users.select(blog).where(users.username==use)
(variable)  = (select 'blog' column from your database where username, of same row, is equal to "use"((session["username"])) variable)
```

This is atleast how it would be done in peewee.
This could then be palced in here:

```py
@app.route("/user")
def user():
    try:
        use = session["username"]

        blog = users.select(blog).where(users.username==use)

        return render_template("user.html", username=use)
    except:
        flash("Need to Login First")
        return redirect(url_for("login"))
```